# Access to store.dispatch in a saga for use with react router redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, redux-saga, react-router-v4

I'm currently refactoring a react + redux + saga + react-router 3 application to use the new react-router 4 due to breaking changes.  Before I would use browserHistory to direct to an appropriate path based on the results from a saga.  Due to react-router 4 changes, I can't use browserHistory any longer.

Now I've incorporated react-router-redux to essentially do what browserHistory did.  The problem is that react-router-redux only works within a store.dispatch, e.g. store.dispatch(push('/')).  I can't seem to find a way to access either the store or it's dispatch function inside my sagas.  Any ideas on how to access store.dispatch within a saga?  I know you can pass arguments in the root saga but I don't know how to retrieve them in my actual sagas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use redux-saga's `put` effect, which dispatches redux actions to the store - [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html#dispatching-actions-to-the-store).

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
// ...

function* fetchProducts() {
  const products = yield call(Api.fetch, '/products')
  // create and yield a dispatch Effect
  yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products })
}
```

Comment: I need to do something like this:  const {error} = yield call(saveAccount)

        if (error) {
            yield put(accountSaveFailed(error))
        } else {
            yield put(dispatch(push('/details')))    
        }

Comment: put is dispatch + yield. You just need `yield put((push('/details'))` (the rest of the condition stays the same).